# Raphael JS rotate group/set not individually

Tags: svg, raphael

I've been toying around with Raphael JS, but failed to find any solution to rotate a group/set of paths as group, and not individually.

**A group/set of path:**

[image: A group/set of path]

**Each element is rotated. Not the entire group/set:**

[image: When group/set is rotated]

**How I do:**

```
var bobble = map.paper.set();

bobble.push(map.paper.add([{
    "fill":fill,
    "stroke":"none",
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    "type":"rect",
    "r": 4
},{
    "fill":fill,
    "stroke":"none",
    x: 100,
    y: 25,
    width: 200,
    height: 50,
    "type":"rect",
    "r": 4
}]));

bobble.rotate(45);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18459985/472495), you've garnered two seemingly good answers, but have not replied to either. Please make a habit of responding, if only to thank people for assisting you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rFuVy/3/)**

```
var paper = Raphael('arrows');

var r1 = paper.rect(100,100,200,10,5).attr({fill:'white'});
var r2 = paper.rect(50,200,100,15,5).attr({fill:'white'});

var st = paper.set(r1,r2);

var l_coord = st.getBBox().x,
    r_coord = st.getBBox().x2,
    t_coord = st.getBBox().y,
    b_coord = st.getBBox().y2;

var cx = (l_coord + r_coord)/2,
    cy = (t_coord + b_coord)/2;

st.rotate(54,cx,cy);
```

[image] 
[image]

Since you need to get your `Raphael set's` center coordinates, you can use `getBBox()` function which returns you:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The set of raphaeljs is a list of element. So, when you use tranform method, it is just a transform of unique element of list in the set.

I had created an plugin which supports **g** tag for my project. But I haven't yet implement the transform method.

```
const SVG = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
function TCRaphael(container, width, height) {
    var paper = new Raphael(container, width, height);
    paper.node = document.getElementById(container).getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
    console.log(paper.node)
    paper.group = function (parent) {
        return new Group(parent);
    };

    function Group(parent) {
        var me = this;
        this.node = document.createElementNS(SVG, "g");
        if (typeof parent !== 'undefined') {
            if (typeof parent.node != 'undefined')
                parent.node.appendChild(me.node);
            else{
                parent.appendChild(me.node);
            }
        }

        this.append = function (child) {
            me.node.appendChild(child.node);
            return child;
        };

        this.appendNode = function (childNode) {
            me.node.appendChild(childNode);
        };

        this.appendTo = function (parent) {
            if (typeof parent !== 'undefined') {
                if (typeof parent.node != 'undefined')
                    parent.node.appendChild(me.node);
                else{
                    parent.appendChild(me.node);
                }
            }
        };

        this.remove = function(){
            me.node.parentNode.remove();
        };

        this.circle = function(x, y, r){
            return me.append(paper.circle(x, y, r));
        };

        this.ellipse =function(x, y, rx, ry){
            return me.append(paper.ellipse(x, y, rx, ry));
        };

        this.image = function(src, x, y, width, height){
            return me.append(paper.image(src, x, y, width, height));
        };

        this.path = function(pathString){
            return me.append(paper.path(pathString));
        };

        this.rect = function(x, y, width, height, r){
            return me.append(paper.rect(x, y, width, height, r));
        };

        this.text = function(x, y, text){
            return me.append(paper.text(x, y, text));
        }


    }
    return paper;
}
```

You can add more function which you want to TCRaphael.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a little easier.

```
myset.transform("R45,20,20")
```

does exactly the same as

```
myset.rotate(45,20,20)  // deprecated
```

the whole **myset** will rotate around the center at 20,20 (maybe the center of the set)
otherwise

```
myset.transform("R45")
```

will rotate each element of the set around it's own center