# Raphael JS combine paths

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm pretty new at SVG and Raphael, but I've been using Illustrator for many years, so I have some assumptions on how it works. I want to combine two paths which should return a single element.

I need to make a speech bubble, but it could be anything really. In this case I tried to make two `rect`, one with round corners and another square `rect` which was rotated. It looked alright, but when I tried to move the speech bubble, the rotated element moved in the wrong direction, because of the 45 degree rotation.

How can I compbine paths which I can later manipulate as if it was a single element/path?

[image: Example of speech bubble]

Comment: I think I gave you good solution. No?

Comment: Hi there. This is an old question, but you have not responded to people who have helped you. Would you consider doing so now?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CHUrB/336/)**

```
var paper = Raphael('canvas',400,400),
    r1    = paper.rect(100,100,200,100).attr({fill:'black'}),
    r2    = paper.rect(130,130,140,40,5).attr({fill:'white','stroke':'white'}),
    r3    = paper.path("M200 170L240 170 220 180z").attr({fill:'white', 'stroke':'white'}), 
    p     = paper.set(r1,r2,r3);

// the rest of the code is in the demo
```

Note, that it is easier to create triangle via `path()` and not worry about rotation.
Good Luck ;)

Comment: Hi @ Brian. I am looking for the opposite of your solution. How would you break apart a compound path? here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847767/how-to-change-an-svgs-complex-paths-that-have-duplicated-paths-for-each-line-to

Answer (score 2):

If you mean merging paths like using the Illustrator `Pathfinder` panel - turning several paths into one path (not a set of paths), merging overlap - I'm pretty sure there's no direct Raphael or SVG equivalent.

The closest thing is, creating a **compound path** (aka composite path) - the equivalent of `cmd-8` or `Object > Make Compound Path` in Illustrator. This merges paths together into one path, but doesn't remove areas of overlap.

Basically, for a set `paper.set( paper.path('M0,0 4,0 0,4z'),paper.path('M9,9 4,9 9,4z') );`, an equivalent compound path would be `paper.path('M0,0 4,0 0,4z M9,9 4,9 9,4z');` - just joining the path definitions into one, each starting with its own `M`.

**Some differences to Raphael sets:**

- Less overhead (it's just one complex path, not several separate individual path elements)
- Fewer surprises when you move it, sort it, etc:

  - Things applied to a Raphael set apply to each item in turn, not to the set as a unit - so for example `toFront()` changes the order ***within*** the set, and transforms centre around ***each item***, like Illustrator's `transform each`, unless you give the transform static co-ordinates.
  - Things applied to a compound path, however, apply to the whole compound path as one unit.
- It's not possible for subpaths of a compound path to have different attributes
- Things like gradients apply once across the whole of the compound path, whereas with sets, there will be separate gradients on each separate path

**[JSBIN demo](http://jsbin.com/uWUfIJOg/1/edit)** - compare the gradients, and see how the compound pair is just one path on the DOM.

---

Here's a simple plugin that adds the ability to take a set and create a compound path from it:

```
Raphael.st.compoundPath = function(){
    var positions = [];
    this.forEach( function( element ){
        positions.push( element.compoundPath() );
    });
    return positions.join('');
} 
Raphael.el.compoundPath = function(){
    var path = this.attr('path');
    return path ? Raphael.parsePathString( path ).join('') : '';
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var someSet = paper.set(paper.path('M0,0 4,0 0,4z'),paper.path('M9,9 4,9 9,4z'));
var compPath = paper.path( someSet.compoundPath() );
someSet.remove(); // if you want to replace the set with a compound path
```

Note that it only combines paths in a set - if you need to combine other shapes with paths, you'll need a way to convert them into paths first.

Comment: Hi @ user568458. I am looking for the opposite of your solution. How would you break apart a compound path? here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847767/how-to-change-an-svgs-complex-paths-that-have-duplicated-paths-for-each-line-to

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you could push your 2 elements into a Raphael set which you would later move with `Element.transform()`. This would let you apply the move handler once, and not twice.

Also for your issue, it is acually [documented](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform):

> ... There are also alternative “absolute” translation, rotation and
>   scale: T, R and S. They will not take previous transformation into
>   account. For example, ...T100,0 will always move element 100 px
>   horisontally, while ...t100,0 could move it vertically if there is r90
>   before. Just compare results of r90t100,0 and r90T100,0. ...