# Compound paths in snap.svg

Tags: snap.svg

How can I create compound paths in snap.svg? A simple example would be two concentric circles, which create a "donut" shape. Is there a nice way of combining these two circles into a compound path?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [How to achieve 'donut holes' with paths in Raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349651/how-to-achieve-donut-holes-with-paths-in-raphael), I've converted the accepted answer to Snap.svg.

```
var d = s.path("M 50 50 L 50 150 L 150 150 L 150 50 z" +
          " M 75 75 L 125 75 L 125 125 L 75 125 z")
d.attr({"fill": "#f00"})
```

Comment: Hi @kevin-hakanson.Your answer is up! And I am looking for the opposite of your solution please.Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847767/how-to-change-an-svgs-complex-paths-that-have-duplicated-paths-for-each-line-to

Answer (score 0):

If you have the two paths as string1 and string2, you could try something like...

```
var paths = s.path([string1,string2]);
```